# Chapter 5: Are there multiple Endings?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I just finished Episode 5 and wondered, if there were alternative endings or game branches. I brought the whole group with me, and am wondering what would have changed if different people accompined me, and if the episode is possible to play out differenly.

> On my playthrough, Lee killed the stranger, and on the run back to Christa and Omid, was to weak to continue. Clementine shot him. Kenny died along with Ben after he fell off the building. And Lee was cut off Christa and Omid after they went over the "bridge" first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From comparing a few different reviews and my playthrough as well as my friends, I can say that aside from a few different scenes along the last chapter and its end, the game plays out mostly the same. The following is what I know:

> When visiting the shelter (end of ch. 4), anyone in the group can stay or not (Omid & Chirsta either both come or both stay), if Ben is with the group he can come along as well depending if you get there alone; If you're not alone in the shelter, you have the option of cutting off your arm or not. Your infection will spread either way; Coming back home the boat will be gone. If anyone stayed behind he'll be locked inside the shed; On the way to the sign/bridge, if you have Ben with you, he'll fall off a broken balcony and be impaled. Kenny will be "overrun" protecting him (not implied if dead or not). If Ben isn't with you, Christa will fall down a skylight and Kenny will help her out, but he'll be overrun afterwards (again, not implied if dead or not); The bridge breaks when Lee crosses it whether Omid & Christa crossed before or not. You'll be separated either case. Omid & Christa won't return (unless you assume they are the shadowed figures in the post-credits scene); If you kept a weapon while talking with the stranger, you can attack him yourself, otherwise Clem will attack him. You may kill him or spare his life; Lee will collapse after Clem sees her parents. Near the security guy Lee can tell Clem to kill him or just leave him chained. If kept alive, Lee will turn. Clementine leaves either way; The end credits scene doesn't seem affected by any choice in the episode.

Comment: Sorry for the giant spoiler section, if anyone can break it down to multiple paragraphs without breaking the spoiler hide feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: It's probably unnecessary to add a spoiler tag in an answer to a question that specifically asks for the spoilers.

Comment: The title asks if there are many endings. The question body specifically asks what would have changed. Either way, bad question to peek at if you don't want spoilers!

Comment: You can't attack the stranger, he'll shoot you.

Answer (score 4):

I've played it 4 times with different choices and it still ends the same:

> Lee dies and Clem walks through a field, seeing 2 people or walkers far away.